# How to use a combobox to search for more that one fields in a record ms access?

Tags: ms-access, macros, combobox

I have a combo box on a form that searches for records on the form. It Works fine However, I wanted to modify the after update event macro so the `Where Condition` matches 2 fields in the same record where both fields are represented by two column in the same combobox. 
this is what I have

```
Where Condition=="[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format([Screen].[ActiveControl],"mm/dd/yyyy") & "#"
```

I want to modify this combobox to search for both `[WorkDate]` and another text field called `[WorkType]`.

I have gone ahead and do a combobox search for the [WorkType] field and got this

```
Where Condition=="[WorkType] = " & "'" & [Screen].[ActiveControl] & "'
```

any help on how to merge these search criteria would be much appreciated

Comment: are these data in two separate comboboxes?

Comment: I want one combobox to search for a record meeting both data. each record consist of WorkDate, WorkType and Comment. I would like to have one combobox to search for a record by WorkDate and WorkType.

Comment: How would you set up your combo box then? If one combobox searches two columns those columns either need to always be in sync (in which point searching for both is pointless) or you are doing a 'select distinct' on those two columns to get the content of your combobox. I'm still confused.

Comment: what is presently happening is the combobox drop down with the WorkDate | WorkType | Comment. and goes to the first record based on field based on WorkDate. The user then has to next through the records until they get to the WorkType they want. even though they selected the correct combination from the combobox. I hope Im making sence. if not may have to do some screen shots

Answer (score 0):

Since your data are in one combobox but your search criteria are in different columns you can construct your query like this

combobox columns: `WorkDate | WorkType | Comment`

```
"[WorkDate] = " & "#" & Format(cboYourComboBox.column(0),"mm/dd/yyyy") & _ 
"# and [WorkType] = " & "'" & cboYourComboBox.column(0) & "'"
```

If you no longer use `Screen.ActiveControl` you can use this same code for the `AfterUpdate` event of both comboboxes.